# no New Repeat button in toolbox in Orbeon 3.9.1 PE

Tags: orbeon

I am using Orbeon 3.9.1 PE. I would not found 'New Repeat' control with toolbox inside Form Builder. I Have changed resources.xml and I got the 'New Repeat' control label in Form Builder. Then I add this snippet of code in toolbox.xml --

```
<xforms:group context="$current-top-level-block" ref="instance('fb-variables')/grids-triggers" appearance="xxforms:internal">
      <xhtml:div class="fb-tool">
            <fr:button appearance="full">
                <xforms:label>
                    <xhtml:img src="/apps/fr/style/images/silk/table_add.png" alt=""/>
                    <xhtml:span><xforms:output value="$form-resources/new-repeat/label"/></xhtml:span>
                </xforms:label>
                <xforms:action ev:event="DOMActivate">

                    <xforms:insert context="$current-top-level-block" nodeset="fr:section | fr:repeat | fr:grid"
                                   at="index('fb-section-content-repeat')" position="after"
                                   origin="......"/>


                </xforms:action>                  
            </fr:button>
     </xhtml:div>
</xforms:group>
```

And I found in model.xml file

React to a focus on a repeat but it is empty-- <

xforms:action ev:event="DOMFocusIn" ev:target="fb-section-content-grid-td-repeat" > TODO: anything here?  <

/xforms:action>

Can anyone please suggest me how to make working the 'New Repeat' control button inside toolbox in form builder with orbeon 3.9.1 PE ?

Answer (score 0):

Repeats in Form Builder are a [new feature of Orbeon Forms 4.0](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/release-notes/40#TOC-Scope-of-the-4.0-release), so you won't be able to use them in 3.9. As of this writing, the final version of 4.0 hasn't been released yet, but you can already use or experiment with [4.0 milestone builds](http://www.orbeon.com/forms/download).